# Python: Read tree like data from text file and store in dictionary

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have a text file containing tree like data separated by a space with following structure:
'Number of branches' 'Name of node' ... 0 (0 means no further branch)
For example:

```
1 A 3 B 2 C 0 
        D 0
    E 1 F 0
    G 2 H 0
      I 0
```

the corresponding dictionary 'tree' should be like:

```
tree = {'A': {'B': {'C': {},
                    'D': {}},
              'E': {'F': {}},
              'G': {'H': {},
                    'I': {}}}}
```

I think recursive way is the right way to do it but I am unable to make it work. I have following function so far:

```
def constructNodes(branch):

    global nodes_temp

    if not branch:
        branch = deque(file.readline().strip().split())
    node1 = branch.popleft()
    nodes_temp.add(node1)
    nbBranches = int(branch.popleft())
    for i in xrange(nbBranches):
        constructNodes(branch)
    return nodes_temp
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your `tree` is not a valid Python object.

Comment: May be, I must have checked it before to post. 'tree' is what I want to get after reading from file. so I made it myself manually, perhaps i did some mistakes. i have corrected the tree now. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a deque to iterate through a sequence, you can use a regular python iterable. That can make things a lot more concise.

```
data = """
1 A 3 B 2 C 0 
        D 0
    E 1 F 0
    G 2 H 0
      I 0"""

def construct_nodes(data):
    return dict((next(data), construct_nodes(data))
                for _ in xrange(int(next(data))))

print construct_nodes(iter(data.split()))
```

Comment: This is more concise and gives same results as the code above. Thanks a lot for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
from collections import deque

data = deque('''\
1 A 3 B 2 C 0 
        D 0
    E 1 F 0
    G 2 H 0
      I 0'''.split())

def constructNodes():
    D = {}
    count = int(data.popleft())
    for _ in range(count):
        node = data.popleft()
        D[node] = constructNodes()
    return D
tree = constructNodes()
print(tree)
```

Output:

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {}, 'D': {}}, 'G': {'H': {}, 'I': {}}, 'E': {'F': {}}}}
```

With some formatting:

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {},
             'D': {}},
       'G': {'H': {},
             'I': {}},
       'E': {'F': {}}}}
```

Comment: Thank a lot Mark, that's what I was looking for. The formatting of output was just to make it easy for reading. Your code works like a charm.